# SQLiteException: table contacts has no column age - Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am trying to create a table in a SQLite database in Android. I set everything up but it keeps telling me I have no column "age", when I clearly do! Can anyone help?

```
// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";
private static final String KEY_AGE = "age";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT," + KEY_AGE + "TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS titles");
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put a space in the `String` where you declare the `age` column:

```
...+ KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT," + KEY_AGE + " TEXT" + ")";
```

Also, after you do this you'll want to uninstall the app and then reinstall it for this modification to take place(so the `onCreate` method will be called again).

Comment: @Nelson.b.austin You uninstalled the application and then reinstalled it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a space character before `TEXT` in the below code:

```
KEY_AGE + "TEXT"
```